# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, customization

i want to add new field in aspnet user table ..i have also added username property in account view model ..

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public DateTime? ActiveUntil;

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string  UserName { get; set; }
```

}

It is giving following error 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

```
      {
Line 53:             // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
Line 54:             var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
Line 55:             // Add custom user claims here
```

Comment: @TAHA SULTAN TEMURI Could you please explain in more details the reasons for your bounty? The question is fairly old and it looks like it has been sufficiently answered already (albeit not accepted by OP).

Comment: actually I had the same issue weeks ago so I decided to start bounty just then I found solution , that's why now waiting for close.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by putting a random string in the SecurityStamp field. To generate this string simply use Guid.NewGuid ()

So, you can change your code to something like this:`enter code here`

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SecurityStamp))
    {
        this.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
    }

    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    return userIdentity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same error. I found that in the `Model` when I change `[Display]` to this:

```
[Display(Name = "")]
public string Budget { get; set; }
```

Instead of this:

```
[Display(Name = "Budget")]
public string Budget { get; set; }
```

The `value` of name is not defined...