# What could be the problem if the error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value: appears upon selecting a link?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, runtime-error

I have an ASP.NET website that is hosted on IIS which has a number of applications. Below is what the applications at the IIS path on the web server looks like.

[image: IIS Path Directory]

[image: IIS Dashboard]

When I log into the specific application, this is what part of the home screen looks like.

[image: App Home Screen]

My issue is specifically with the Admin application. The Admin application corresponds to the **Administration** link button of the apps home page.

When we click the **Administration** link on the home page, the below runtime error appears.

[image: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value" error]

There is no issue with the application files as I have exactly the same application files running in another environment with no issues. We have tried reverting to an older version of the specific application, and it works. So the specific set of application files, don't work on the specific environment.

I have also checked the WebConfigClient configuration files to ensure that they contain the correct settings and they do. I've also found the below issue that - although may be related - is at a programming level whereas my problem is that I don't have access to the code. The developers have assured me that there is no issue. Proof of that is that the specific application runs on another environment.

[Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734275/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-value)

I have checked various IIS settings ranging from **Authentication** related settings and some other basic application settings, but no luck. Every search result I've come across refers to fixes that are code related.

I'm not sure what else I need to inspect to resolve this issue. Since the specific application runs in another environment, it's clear that something is wrong with the specific web server but having checked various options through IIS, the configurations seem to be the same with the working environment and so are the SQL instances/databases/configurations.

I've tried removing the application and re-converting it, I've also tried refreshing and recycling the application with no luck. There is also no issue with the application pool as the rest of the applications work fine. I've also checked and made sure that the web.config file is correct, which it is.

Any ideas on what else could be happening would be appreciated. Hope I've provided a clear picture on the situation. Happy to add clarifications, if needed.

Comment: check the current user and if you give rights then add anonymous user access rights to website for test purpose.. are you able to run from the source code?

Comment: most probably it is related to code line no 505 Site.Master.vb as per error page show. show the code here what written there.

Comment: Are there any unusual entries or error messages in the IIS logs and the Event Viewer logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was an internal setting of the actual application. The application demands a specific input on a specific web form when the Administration link is clicked. This value was not provided and that resulted in the error.